# Ocultar class (owl-item) predeterminada del carrusel con un hijo oculto

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, filtro, owl

Hola ayuda por favor necesito eliminar una clase que owl carrousel le da predeterminada a un div hijo , osea le crea otra div padre con class owl-item , ya que estoy haciendo un filtro y al lograrlo me oculta el hijo pero ese div padre queda vació como un espacio en blanco:

HTML:

```
    <div class="category_list" >
            <ul class="text-left pt-5 listado">Filtrar
                <li><a href="#" class="category_item" category="all">Todas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="category_item" category="uno" >uno</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="category_item" category="dos">dos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="category_item" category="tres">tres</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="category_item" category="cuatro">cuatro</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     <div  class="owl-carousel owl-theme product-list ">
        <div class="product-item" category="clasificados" >
         <h4>uno</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="product-item" category="clasificados" >
         <h4>dos</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="product-item" category="clasificados" >
         <h4>tres</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="product-item" category="clasificados" >
         <h4>cuatro</h4>
        </div>
     </div>
```

JS

```
$('.category_list .category_item[category="all"]').addClass('ct_item-active');

  $('.category_item').click(function(e){

    var catProduct = $(this).attr('category');

        e.preventDefault();
       $('.product-item').css('transform','scale(0)');
        function hideProduct(){
           $('.product-item').hide();
       }setTimeout(hideProduct,400);
```

Comment: La función **removeClass()** de **Jquery** te podría ayudar. https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Comment: Hola miguel no , esa función no me serviría por que como todos los div tienen la misma clase se eliminarían todos , necesito es ocultar los que tienen los hijos div ya ocultados y así

Comment: Podrías mostrarnos la estructura **HTML** que presenta el problema que nos mencionas y luego dejar claro a que **divs** deseas quitar la clase. Con los selectores de **Jquery** se puede determina a que **divs** deseas afectar con sus funciones, pero es difícil ayudarte sin que nos dejes claro esto que te comento.

Comment: si claro pero mira es la misma que te comente en el espacio de arriba yo estoy ocultando con display none el div que tiene la clase ( .product-item ) y realiza la funcion normal pero como es un carrousel owl crea un div padre predeterminado con clase ( .owl-item) el cual entonces queda en espacio en blanco , al inspeccionar se detecta que ese div con clase (.product-item) tiene un div padre asi 

<div class="owl-item active" style="width: 268.333px; margin-right: 10px;"> el cual queda vacio por que el hijo ya tiene un display none

Comment: Ahora si queda claro lo que deseas conseguir. Te escribo una respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitas podría conseguirse poniendo un `display: none` al padre del `div` que ya tienes oculto.

Para ello podemos apoyarnos en la función `parent()` de **Jquery**:

```
$('.product-item').parent().css('display', 'none');
```

Este selector buscaría el padre directo de tu elemento `.product-item` y le pondría un `display: none`.

**EDIT**

Si tan solo quieres ocultar los `div` que sean padre de un elemento `.product-item` que esté oculto puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
$('.product-item:hidden').parent().css('display', 'none');
```

A través del selector `:hidden` se puede conseguir seleccionar el padre de los elementos `.product-item` que no sean visibles.

**Referencia:** [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Comment: a super miguel mil gracias funciono bien , ya lo que me toca verificar es como hacer para que se le de solo a los que tienen el div hijo oculto , ya que se los esta dando a todos.

Comment: He añadido una edición para ayudarte en como podrías conseguir eso que me comentas.